# Endomorphisms of Lie group acting on cotangent space

Tags: lie-groups, abelian-varieties, complex-manifolds, co-tangent-space

Let $G$ be a (complex, compact, commutative) Lie group. Apparently the endomorphism ring $\textrm{End}(G)$ of $G$ (i.e., holomorphic group homomorphisms) acts on the cotangent space $T^\ast_eG$ at the identity $e \in G$.

If $\phi \in \textrm{End}(G)$ and $\omega \in T^\ast_eG$ then
\begin{align}
\phi \cdot \omega = \omega \circ d_e\phi
\end{align}
seems like a reasonable definition of this action.

I have two questions.

(i) Is this the correct action?

(ii) How can I show that the action is faithful?

I think that (ii) holds if I can show $\phi$ is a submersion. For example, if $\phi \cdot \omega = 0$ then $T^\ast_eG = \textrm{im}(d_e\phi) \subseteq \textrm{ker}(\omega)$ so $\omega = 0$. Moreover, $\phi$ will be a submersion if and only if it is an immersion, since it maps from a space to itself.

Some extra facts that may be of use:

(a) I really am interested in $G = \mathbf{C}^g/\Lambda$ where $\Lambda \subseteq \mathbf{C}^g$ is a lattice, i.e., $G$ is a $g$-dimensional torus.

(b) We can assume that any endomorphism is surjective with finite kernel. This is because my endomorphisms are isogenies of abelian varieties.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3761751/is-the-lie-algebra-morphism-induced-by-injective-surjective-lie-group-morphism-a) question.

We have a diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
T^\ast_eG @>{d_e\phi}>> T^\ast_eG \\
@V{\textrm{exp}}VV @VV{\textrm{exp}}V\\
G @>{\phi}>> G.
\end{CD}

Since $G$ is compact, the exponential map is surjective. Hence $\phi$ surjective implies $d_e\phi$ surjective. As remarked in the question, this shows that $\textrm{End}(G)$ acts faithfully on $T^\ast_eG$.

Please let me know if this solution is not correct.